# Babel not laying source maps inline

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I have the `index.js` file:

```
'use strict';

import prompt from 'prompt';

async function test() {
  let i = 0;

  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      i++;
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });

  i++;
}

test().then(() => {
  console.log('done!');
});
```

I use the following command to run it: `node --harmony-async-await -r babel-register --debug-brk=5858 /home/karl/dev/node/test/index.js`

I have the `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

When I run the debugger it transpiles to the following:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 'use strict';

var _prompt = require('prompt');

var _prompt2 = _interopRequireDefault(_prompt);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

async function test() {
  var i = 0;

  await new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      i++;
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });

  i++;
}

test().then(function () {
  console.log('done!');
});
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,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
});
```

I don't know why it isn't laying source maps for the import function?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find any fix?